# What happens actually when I do git fetch and git checkout origin/branch from a local branch where new files are there?

Tags: git, github, git-fetch

Consider I have a local branch `A` and two remote branches `A` and `B`. 
The **local** branch `A` contains **some files** which are not in **remote** `B`.
then, I do as follows: 
 
`git fetch` 
`git checkout origin/B`

> then, those **files from local A** remains there, I removed those files and commit with my required changes in some files which were there in `origin/B`:

`git add .`
`git commit -m "fixes made"`

> then, head got detached with showing the commit hash

So, I have two questions here

1. Why those files from my local branch `A` copied/remained to/in `origin/B`?
2. Why head got detached?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why those files from my local branch A copied/remained to/in origin/B?

Because they *aren't* files from branch A. They're files in your working directory that aren't managed by git. You didn't add them to any commit in branch A or anywhere else. And git doesn't do anything to files that it hasn't been told to manage. Work isn't "on a branch" until you commit it.

> Why head got detached?

Because you did `git checkout origin/B`, which leaves `HEAD` detached. You probably meant `git checkout -t origin/B`, which creates a new branch `B` with an upstream of `origin/B` and points `HEAD` there.

Comment: I am unclear about your last sentence in the second answer. Each branch will have different `HEAD`. So how that actually happens?

Answer (score 2):

[@hobbs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/152948/hobbs) already gave you the [right answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50792854/26396).

To answer the question in [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50792586/what-happens-actually-when-i-do-git-fetch-and-git-checkout-origin-branch-from-a#comment88592955_50792854):

> Each branch will have different `HEAD`. So how that actually happens?

In Git, the word `HEAD` (in capital letters) doesn't mean "*the tip of the branch*" as you might expect<sup>1</sup>; instead, `HEAD` is a special reference that points to the branch you currently have checkout out in your working directory.

The [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#def_branch) says it best:

> A single Git repository can track an arbitrary number of branches, but your working tree is associated with just one of them (the "current" or "checked out" branch), and `HEAD` points to that branch.

Normally `HEAD` points to a branch name<sup>2</sup>, but it could also point to a specific commit. When that happens, it's said to be a "[*detached HEAD*](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#gitglossary-aiddefdetachedHEADadetachedHEAD)".

Now, since you can't commit directly to a [remote tracking branch](https://git-scm.com/book/id/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches#_tracking_branches), when you say:

```
git checkout origin/B
```

`HEAD` ends up pointing *directly* to the commit referenced by `origin/B` instead of a local branch name; thus, it becomes a *detached HEAD*.

---

1. That's called [*"head"*](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#gitglossary-aiddefheadahead), lower case.
2. In fact, there's a text file in the `.git` directory called `HEAD`, which literally contains the name of the branch it points to.